# Link table to dropdown form

Tags: python, web2py

My code currently gives ALL users and also has the id in the dropdown for some reason.

What I'm looking for: You select a user and it gets added to the assignment. And in the dropdown it shouldn't show the user id(Currently shown as: John Doe (1) )

So how do you get just the users that are already in the link table(Or just the ones that are not) and remove the id from the user visible dropdown

```
addUserForm = SQLFORM(db.assignments_users, showid=False, submit_button=T('Add User')).process()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `db.assignments_users` table, presumably there is a reference field that links to the `db.auth_users` table. By default, reference fields get an `IS_IN_DB` validator that accepts all IDs from the linked table. The validator is also used to generate the form's `select` widget, with the values in the widget generated based on the `format` attribute of the linked table. The default `format` attribute of the `db.auth_user` table is `'%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(id)s)'`, which is why you are seeing the `db.auth_user` record ID in parentheses after the name.

You can override the above default behavior by explicitly specifying your own validator for the reference field. The first argument to the `IS_IN_DB` validator can be a `Set` object defining a particular set of records (in case you don't want to list all records in the referenced table). The third argument to `IS_IN_DB` is the `label` argument, which allows you to specify a custom label for each record (either Python string format or a function/lambda):

```
Field('user_id', 'reference auth.user',
      requires=IS_IN_DB(db(query), 'auth_user.id', '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s'))
```

The `query` should be a query that narrows the set of user IDs that you want to include in the list.

Note, when you don't specify the `requires` attribute for a reference field, in addition to automatically getting a default `IS_IN_DB` validator, you also get a default `represent` attribute (based on the `format` attribute of the referenced table). However, when you explicitly include your own `requires` attribute, you no longer get the default `represent` attribute, so you may want to specify that as well:

```
Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user',
      requires=IS_IN_DB(db(query), 'auth_user.id', '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s'),
      represent='%(first_name)s %(last_name)s')
```

Finally, you might want to rethink removing the user ID from the labels. Without the ID, if two users have the same name, the two names will both appear in the list, but there will be no way to tell one from the other.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I need. Now I'm stuck with the other problem that I only want from assignments_users where assignment_id == request.args(0) 
I tried things without succes:
db.assignments_users(db.assignments_users.assignment_id == request.args(0)) 
db(db.assignments_users.assignment_id == request.args(0)) and I have no clue how to do it some other way except writing it myself completely, but I'd expect there to be some sort of function for it

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you talking about filtering the list of users in the `db.assignments_users.user_id` dropdown? That dropdown is populated by the records in `db.auth_user`, not `db.assignments_users`, so how would a query on the latter help? Are you saying you want the list of users in the dropdown to be only those who are already in the `db.assignments_users` table for a given assignment? How would you then ever add a new user to that table? Also, if `request.args(0)` determines the assignment, then your form should not allow the assignment field to be filled by the user.